# Angular 5 wait for promises to return from for loop

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I have the array as below:

```
arr = ['res1', 'res2', 'res3'];
```

Then for each `arr` value, I will do an API call that will return a promise

```
arr.forEach(val => this.getPromise(val));
```

The method `getPromise` returns a promise.
I need to wait for all promises before i invoke another method.  How should I do it?

Comment: this moght be helpful https://daveceddia.com/waiting-for-promises-in-a-loop/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39890818/2742156

Comment: First try building an array of promises, then using [Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and see if that works for you. This way you can execute all in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to perform an action after all promises have resolved. It takes an array of promises:

```
const promises = ["val1", "val2"].map(val => this.getPromise(val));

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => console.log(results)) // this is an array
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

You can use then() and catch() as you would with a promise. The response is an array of resolved values.

Hopefully that helps!